Connecting minio storage from node with private bucket
We are using minio storage for storing data in my project. I have to access minio from Node server, below is the configuration I am using -
export default new MinioClient({
  endPoint: config.minioEndPoint,
  port: 9000,
  useSSL: false,
  accessKey: config.minioAccessKey,
  secretKey: config.minioSecretKey,
});

It works fine when my bucket settings is public (Access policy). I want to access my bucket with access policy as private.
I tried useSSL: true, above but it did not work. I also tried port: 443. It did not work either. Does anyone have any idea how to connect to private buckets. ?

When I use useSSL as true, it gives this error
"Failed to get workflow file: Error: write EPROTO D42C0000:error:0A00010B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:355:\n"
